# ISO27001 and open software

Tags: openvpn

The company am employed considers to obtain an ISO27001 certification. Have already implemented a Linux testbed running Open VPN without issues. However am told a company cannot be ISO27001 certified unless their VPN is materialized using commercial only solutions, *implying open solutions such as Open VPN are considered unacceptable and un-certifiable under ISO27001*. Was surprised to hear this, would like to know from more knowledgeable people if there is any substance on that.

kind regards

K

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: Am an IT developer, yet OpenVPN is not about programming, as most posters will use it as is without altering the underlined code. Nearly every question I have seen in regard of this topic at this forum is a how to one. Therefore I conclude that arguing on this base is most probably meaningless. Was not aware of the Super User extension and its role across the forum. In any case, at this point I consider the subject closed and I do not expect further input.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OpenVPN is covered within this forum and in good depth, although most of it has got nothing to do with programming.

At this point I have concluded my own research from other sources and have found there are no restrictions in employing Open Software within the scope of an ISO27001 certification. In that sense, OpenVPN can be used within the scope of an ISO27001 certification.

Looks one specific outsourcer has attempted to sell us their software together with their ISO27001 'experience'. For the record we have declined them both.

Comment: *ISO27001 is about the security of a company’s IT infrastructure, which makes it an IT oriented topic* Exactly - IT infrastructure isn't a programming topic. And you'll notice that the vast majority of non-programming questions in this tag are closed as off-topic.